# Sort numpy data by array of indices (both data and indices may contain `np.nan`!)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, nan

I want to reorganize this array

```
values = np.array([[-0.00127687, -0.0384767 , -0.99925868],
                   [-0.16354917,  0.075218  ,  0.98366352],
                   [-0.64543092,  0.75546703, -0.11264323],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

in an order described by this array

```
order = np.array([ 5.,  4.,  0., nan, nan, nan])
```

Each value in the `order` array represents the position the corresponding data should be moved to. Do you know of an elegant solution, how to rearrange this?

I know how to write a `for` loop that would do the trick, but performance is my primary goal here, since this function may be called several thousand times per program execution.

EDIT:

For clarification - the expected output would look like this:

```
output = np.array([[-0.64543092,  0.75546703, -0.11264323],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan],
                   [        nan,         nan,         nan],
                   [-0.16354917,  0.075218  ,  0.98366352],
                   [-0.00127687, -0.0384767 , -0.99925868]])
```

Comment: what's the expected output in this case?

Comment: Appended the expected output to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to initalize an array of `nan`s and then copy the values into the new array only at the positions where the value in the `order` array is valid and not `nan`.

```
result = np.empty_like(values)
result[:] = np.nan
valid_indices = ~np.isnan(order)
result[order[valid_indices].astype(int)] = values[valid_indices]
```